GLSL shader difference between desktop and mobile - varyings or noise function?
Context
I'm building a WebGL GLSL shader using a 3d Perlin Noise function to warp the vertices as well as color the fragments so they line up with the vertices.
I'm running the Perlin Noise function in both the vertex and fragment shader.
You can see this running on Shaderfrog and you can modify the code here.
The problem
On mobile, the fragment and vertex Perlin noise outputs line up exactly creating a pleasing effect:

However, on desktop, the fragment and vertex perlin noise function output do not agree, causing them to be misaligned:

The Perlin noise functions are identical between the fragment and vertex shaders. You can see the definition of both functions by click on the "GLSL Editor" tab and selecting either "Perlin Noise (fragment)" for the fragment code, or "Vertex Displacement (Vertex)" for the vertex code:

For posterity, I'm posting the fragment code here, but I don't think it matters:
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

//  Classic Perlin 3D Noise 
//  by Stefan Gustavson
//
vec4 permute(vec4 x){return mod(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x, 289.0);}
vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r){return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;}
vec3 fade(vec3 t) {return t*t*t*(t*(t*6.0-15.0)+10.0);}

float noise(vec3 P){
  vec3 Pi0 = floor(P); // Integer part for indexing
  vec3 Pi1 = Pi0 + vec3(1.0); // Integer part + 1
  Pi0 = mod(Pi0, 289.0);
  Pi1 = mod(Pi1, 289.0);
  vec3 Pf0 = fract(P); // Fractional part for interpolation
  vec3 Pf1 = Pf0 - vec3(1.0); // Fractional part - 1.0
  vec4 ix = vec4(Pi0.x, Pi1.x, Pi0.x, Pi1.x);
  vec4 iy = vec4(Pi0.yy, Pi1.yy);
  vec4 iz0 = Pi0.zzzz;
  vec4 iz1 = Pi1.zzzz;

  vec4 ixy = permute(permute(ix) + iy);
  vec4 ixy0 = permute(ixy + iz0);
  vec4 ixy1 = permute(ixy + iz1);

  vec4 gx0 = ixy0 / 7.0;
  vec4 gy0 = fract(floor(gx0) / 7.0) - 0.5;
  gx0 = fract(gx0);
  vec4 gz0 = vec4(0.5) - abs(gx0) - abs(gy0);
  vec4 sz0 = step(gz0, vec4(0.0));
  gx0 -= sz0 * (step(0.0, gx0) - 0.5);
  gy0 -= sz0 * (step(0.0, gy0) - 0.5);

  vec4 gx1 = ixy1 / 7.0;
  vec4 gy1 = fract(floor(gx1) / 7.0) - 0.5;
  gx1 = fract(gx1);
  vec4 gz1 = vec4(0.5) - abs(gx1) - abs(gy1);
  vec4 sz1 = step(gz1, vec4(0.0));
  gx1 -= sz1 * (step(0.0, gx1) - 0.5);
  gy1 -= sz1 * (step(0.0, gy1) - 0.5);

  vec3 g000 = vec3(gx0.x,gy0.x,gz0.x);
  vec3 g100 = vec3(gx0.y,gy0.y,gz0.y);
  vec3 g010 = vec3(gx0.z,gy0.z,gz0.z);
  vec3 g110 = vec3(gx0.w,gy0.w,gz0.w);
  vec3 g001 = vec3(gx1.x,gy1.x,gz1.x);
  vec3 g101 = vec3(gx1.y,gy1.y,gz1.y);
  vec3 g011 = vec3(gx1.z,gy1.z,gz1.z);
  vec3 g111 = vec3(gx1.w,gy1.w,gz1.w);

  vec4 norm0 = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(g000, g000), dot(g010, g010), dot(g100, g100), dot(g110, g110)));
  g000 *= norm0.x;
  g010 *= norm0.y;
  g100 *= norm0.z;
  g110 *= norm0.w;
  vec4 norm1 = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(g001, g001), dot(g011, g011), dot(g101, g101), dot(g111, g111)));
  g001 *= norm1.x;
  g011 *= norm1.y;
  g101 *= norm1.z;
  g111 *= norm1.w;

  float n000 = dot(g000, Pf0);
  float n100 = dot(g100, vec3(Pf1.x, Pf0.yz));
  float n010 = dot(g010, vec3(Pf0.x, Pf1.y, Pf0.z));
  float n110 = dot(g110, vec3(Pf1.xy, Pf0.z));
  float n001 = dot(g001, vec3(Pf0.xy, Pf1.z));
  float n101 = dot(g101, vec3(Pf1.x, Pf0.y, Pf1.z));
  float n011 = dot(g011, vec3(Pf0.x, Pf1.yz));
  float n111 = dot(g111, Pf1);

  vec3 fade_xyz = fade(Pf0);
  vec4 n_z = mix(vec4(n000, n100, n010, n110), vec4(n001, n101, n011, n111), fade_xyz.z);
  vec2 n_yz = mix(n_z.xy, n_z.zw, fade_xyz.y);
  float n_xyz = mix(n_yz.x, n_yz.y, fade_xyz.x); 
  return 2.2 * n_xyz;
}
/* 
* SMOOTH MOD
* - authored by @charstiles -
* based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491494/does-there-exist-a-smooth-approximation-of-x-bmod-y
* (axis) input axis to modify
* (amp) amplitude of each edge/tip
* (rad) radius of each edge/tip
* returns => smooth edges
*/

float smoothMod(float axis, float amp, float rad){
    float top = cos(PI * (axis / amp)) * sin(PI * (axis / amp));
    float bottom = pow(sin(PI * (axis / amp)), 2.0) + pow(rad, 2.0);
    float at = atan(top / bottom);
    return amp * (1.0 / 2.0) - (1.0 / PI) * at;
}

float fit(float unscaled, float originalMin, float originalMax, float minAllowed, float maxAllowed) {
  return (maxAllowed - minAllowed) * (unscaled - originalMin) / (originalMax - originalMin) + minAllowed;
}

float wave(vec3 position) {
  return fit(smoothMod(position.y * density, 1.0, 1.5), 0.35, 0.6, 0.0, 1.0);
}

// the function which defines the displacement
float displace(vec3 point) {
  vec3 coords = point;
  coords.xy += speed * time;
  vec3 noisePattern = vec3(noise(coords));
  float pattern = wave(noisePattern + (vec3(speed, 0.0) * time));
  float displacement = pattern * displaceHeight;
  return displacement;
}

In the vertex shader, I call the perlin noise function seeded by the model's untransformed position:
in vec3 position;
varying vec3 vPosition;

void main() {
  float displacement = displace(position);
  ...
  vPosition = position;
}

And in the fragment shader, I use the vPosition varying to generate the fragment color:
varying vec3 vPosition;

void main() {
  float displaced = displace(vPosition);
  float colorOut = clamp((displaced - 0.5) * 10.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(colorOut), 1.0);
}

You can see that the call to displace() uses the position attribute in the vertex shader, and that same value is passed as vPosition as a varying to the fragment shader.
I have verified that the uniforms, density and speed, are identical between both fragment and vertex shader.
Because this lines up perfectly on mobile, I believe the math is correct. I'm wondering if there's some difference in how varyings are passed between vertex and fragment on mobile vs desktop. Like the precision maybe? But both vertex and fragment shaders have the same precision set at the top.
If you want to try editing the shader in Shaderfrog you can either edit the individual source code nodes and click compile, or you can click the Shader -> Fragment/Vertex subtab, and live edit the compiled code directly.

I also exported the final compiled shader code to text on both mobile and desktop, and confirmed that both vertex and fragment shaders were the same code.

This does not appear to be a mobile vs desktop thing anymore. This seems specific to my own macbook. I am not able to reproduce on other laptops.

I now suspect this is because I'm on Big Sur and a 10 year old laptop

this line float bottom = pow(sin(PI * (axis / amp)), 2.0) + pow(rad, 2.0); seem suspect. pow of a negative number is undefined and so will be different on different machines. Try float bottom = pow(abs(sin(PI * (axis / amp))), 2.0) + pow(rad, 2.0); and see if things start matching

@gman thank you for the thought! It doesn't look like that has an effect on the shader after trying abs(). I also don't see any other pow() calls in the shader.
